# Creating a struct, that has an exchangable function

Tags: rust, closures, constants

I would like to have a struct, that contains a function set by the user of that struct. I came up with something like this:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    some_function: Fn(f64) -> f64
}
```

I then want to define a set of constants that can be picked when creating a `MyStruct` instance. I tried it like this:

```
pub const SIGMOID: Fn(f64) -> f64 = |x| 1.0 / (1.0 + E.powf(x));
```

I get a compile error, that the `Fn(f64) -> f64` doesn't have a size known at compile-time and a warning to use the `dyn` keyword. I don't want to use the `dyn` keyword, because of the performance penalty. Do I have to put that constant on the heap using `Box` or is there a more lightweight way to do this? I think there's gonna be a performance penalty when storing it on the heap too or am I mistaken here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no performance penalty to the `dyn` keyword versus not using it. Not using it is considered unclear and will not be supported in a future version of Rust.

Given that `Fn(f64) -> f64` is a trait, any type could implement it, and any two functions are considered different types. If you want to be flexible enough to use any implementor of this trait, then you will *need* to use dynamic dispatch — which I presume is the performance hit you want to avoid.

You can get full generality, using dynamic dispatch by boxing the function, so the field only contains a pointer, which has a known size. The actual function will be allocated on the heap, and can have any size.

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    someFunction: Box<dyn Fn(f64) -> f64>,
}
```

If you absolutely cannot bear to use dynamic dispatch, you can use a *function pointer* instead of a trait object. A function pointer is a special type (not a trait), that `fn` items can be coerced to. Most closures however *cannot* be coerced to a function pointer because they would need to implement `Copy`. Essentially that means the "closure" doesn't close over anything and could have just as easily have been written as a function item. That would look like this:

```
pub struct MyStruct {
    // Notice: lower case fn
    some_function: fn(f64) -> f64,
}

// Notice: lower case fn
pub const SIGMOID: fn(f64) -> f64 = |x| 1.0 / (1.0 + E.powf(x));

fn main() {
    let s = MyStruct {
        some_function: SIGMOID,
    };
}
```

Comment: Wow that is exactly what I was looking for. Are function pointers a new feature? When I was last doing Rust (start of 2018) I did not come across them. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To quote the [`Fn` ***trait*** docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html):

> *This trait (`Fn`) is not to be confused with [function pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html) (`fn`).*

Function pointers don't allow you to have state in a closure-like way. If you're using something like the `sigmoid` function, which is defined without state, you can use that. If you're using a closure with state, you *need* to have some form of dynamic dispatch or generic type, because you cannot name the type of a closure.

For example, with `fn` poitners:

```
struct Foo {
    my_func: fn(f64) -> f64
}
```

Or with dynamic dispatch and references:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    my_func: &'a dyn Fn(f64) -> f64,
}
```

*Or* with a mutable state:

```
struct Foo<'a> {
    my_func: &'a mut dyn FnMut(f64) -> f64,
}
```

Without a lifetime:

```
struct Foo {
   my_func: Box<dyn FnMut(f64) -> f64>
}
```

> I think there's gonna be a performance penalty when storing it on the heap too or am I mistaken here?

Yes, there's frequently a penalty with dynamic dispatch due to the double indirection of going through the vtable. *I believe*, I'm not sure, there's also a penalty because of a lack of monomorphization. But, these are both not important unless they're quantifiable.

> ```
> pub const SIGMOID: Fn(f64) -> f64 = |x| 1.0 / (1.0 + E.powf(x));
> ```

This can become

```
pub const SIGMOID: fn(f64) -> f64 = |x| 1.0 / (1.0 + E.powf(x));
```

And [`fn` pointers](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.fn.html) implement all of the `Fn*` traits:

> In addition, function pointers of *any* signature, ABI, or safety are [`Copy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html), and all *safe* function pointers implement [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html), [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html), and [`FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html). This works because these traits are specially known to the compiler.